# Having troubles creating a wildcard sql code with multiple inputs

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently working on creating a query that will pull data from a table that is linked on a certain part #. The challenge with this is the part #'s in the table have leading zeros. For example the part number I have is 8456790 but is stored in our table as 00000008456790. I'm able to get the desired results for one value using the following code:

```
select ZMATNR, ZLPN
FROM   tblZMMGPNXREF
WHERE ZMATNR like ('%8456790%')
```

I have  roughly 8,000 part #'s I want to run this code for but I know the syntax doesn't allow for me to paste all 8,000 parts at once.

Is there a quick way to run this code including all 8,000 part #s?

Comment: Why is the part number showing as `8456790` and also as `00000008456790`. Are you using different data types? If so, you should fix the database.

Comment: What's the database? Sybase, Teradata, MySQL, etc.

Comment: Using MySQL sorry for the confusion

Comment: Where are those 8000 part numbers you want to search for? In another table? If so, a single JOIN could get all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

In most databases casting `'00000008456790'` to an integer should be enough:

```
select ZMATNR, ZLPN
FROM   tblZMMGPNXREF
WHERE cast(ZMATNR as int) = 8456790
```

In Mysql it's even easier because of implicit conversion of `'00000008456790'` to the integer `8456790` when they are compared:

```
select ZMATNR, ZLPN
FROM   tblZMMGPNXREF
WHERE ZMATNR = 8456790
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it has to do with how the table is structured but whenever I run it as if its an integer I get this error "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'V' to data type int.
"

Comment: What is `V`? Are there letters included in the value of the column `ZMATNR`?

Comment: Even if there where letters, in MySql you would not get such an error.

Comment: Sorry I got my wires crossed, this is SQL Server not MySQL

Comment: In SQL Server my 1st query should work if the values of `ZMATNR` are as you say in the question. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f3325af425419da87f0a425cd2f4155

Comment: Still getting this error: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'V' to data type int.

Comment: Examine the values of the column `ZMATNR`. Do they contain only numbers or not?